# Values set using req.setAttribute in interceptor sometimes evaluate to null

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have written a interceptor that checks `api-session-token` against db. It then sets corresponding `userId` and `userRole` in request object using

```
req.setAttribute("userId", userId);
req.setAttribute("userRole", userRole);
```

I am accessing those values in controller. This works only some times. for two consecutive requests of same type, same values. One evaluates to correct values while other gives `null`

I have checked that I am not using `setAttribute` anywhere else. I have also checked that values I am getting from db and setting in req object are not `null`.

```
public class ApiSessionInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(request.getMethod().matches(RequestMethod.OPTIONS.name())) {
            return true;
        }
        setRequest(request);
        setResponse(response);
        if (!checkSession()) {
            throw new HttpUnauthorizedException();

        }

        return true;
    }
private boolean checkSession() {

        String sessionKey = getHeaderSessionKey();
        if (sessionKey != null) {

            Map<String, String> result = apiSessionService.getUserIdAndRoleBySessionKey(sessionKey);
            if(result!=null) {
                this.setUserId(result.get("user_id"));
                this.setUserRole(CommonMethods.getRoleNameFromId(result.get("role_id")));
                request.setAttribute("userId", this.getUserId());
                request.setAttribute("role", this.getUserRole());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Controller is simply

```
public class SampleController{

@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    public ModelAndView downloadProcess(Model model,
                                @RequestBody FileDownloadProcessDto fileDownloadProcessDto,
                                HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
LOGGER.debug("userId:"+ req.getAttribute("userId");
return null;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to extend HandlerInterceptorAdapter in which you set attributes to request, right?

Can you please share the piece of your interceptor and the place where you are accessing request attributes in controller?

[edit]

I created following spring-boot application and it works in 100% of cases. Are you sure your attribute in fact is not null and it is set properly? 
Are you sure your request is not wrapped or replaced in some filter?

The interceptor mapping:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    HandlerInterceptor userHandlerInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(userHandlerInterceptor);

    }
}
```

The interceptor:

`package com.example.demo;`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class UserHandlerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(request.getMethod().matches(RequestMethod.OPTIONS.name())) {
            return true;
        }
        request.setAttribute("userId", "USER_ID");
        return true;
    }


}
```

The controller:

`package com.example.demo;`

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String downloadProcess(Model model, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res){
        System.out.println( req.getAttribute("userId"));
        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: added requested details.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Only filter I have is cors (cross origin request) filter, which is not applied to this particular API.

I did some further testing. This only happens when 2 **consecutive requests are made from same client, within fractions of seconds of each other.**